# Как правильно писать: "рОзливные" или "рАзливные духи"?

Tags: орфография

Возник тут у нас спор, который продолжается уже некоторое время, как же все таки правильна пишется. "Розливные духи" или "Разливные духи"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В безударном положении есть только РАЗ (РАС) - РаспускАть - рОспуск, рАзливать - рОзлив. 
Духи рАзливные.

Answer (score 1):

Разливной, разумеется.
Добавлю, что "разливной" и "разыскной" - два слова, написание которых традиционно сталкивается с возражениеми профессиональной среды, мотивирующей написание словами "рОзлив" и "рОзыск". Последнее даже одно время считалось единственным исключением из правила "без ударения - О", нормативным считалось "розыскной", но сейчас и это уже в прошлом.
На самом деле подобные возражения ничем не мотивированы. Во-первых слово "рОзлив" является в лучщем случае профессилональным жаргонизмом (нормативно разлИв), во-вторых это не основание для написания "розливной".

Comment: "Последнее даже одно время считалось единственным исключением из правила "без ударения - О", нормативным считалось "розыскной" - и правда, было. Спасибо, напомнили.

Answer (score 0):

Повтор вопроса.
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/81/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2